# What to do when MySQL is not generating any logs at all on Debian?

Tags: mysql, logs, debian

The problem I'm having is that MySQL (5.5.46-0+deb7u1) is not generating log files. This on Debian Wheezy.

The my.cfg file has been updated according to the required config for logging ALL queries (as per http://www.microhowto.info/howto/log_all_queries_to_a_mysql_server.html). It's not writing to the specified location, nor to the default location.

Mysql errors are also not being logged, as far as I can tell.

EDIT: my.cnf is here: http://pastie.org/private/q9vwgihslpenc94mxmyyiw

EDIT: Here's the output of "show variables like '%warn%';":

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_warnings  | 1     |
| sql_warnings  | OFF   |
| warning_count | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: could You attache my.cnf file?
result of - show variables like '%warn%'; ?

Comment: ok, I've edited the question with that info.

Comment: Are you sure the location(s) exist and are writable by the mysql user?

Comment: They exist, I'm not sure what the ownership / permissions should be on debian?

Comment: normal error file not enables as I can see , like log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log

next good to check ls -l /var/log/mysql for permission

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to commenters for their insights. The solutions was:

1. Add "log_errors = /var/log/mysql/mysql.err" to my.cnf
2. See permissions error in error log
3. chmod log files to "mysql:root"

Comment: check as well permission for whole folder - /var/log/mysql in this case in feature not need check single file permissions

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by restarting mysql.

```bash
systemctl stop mysql.service
systemctl start mysql.service
```

It changed from:

> ```
> total 715008
> -rw-r----- 1 mysql adm           0 Oct 30 00:00 error.log
> -rw-r----- 1 mysql adm           0 Oct 29 00:00 error.log.1
> ```

to:

> ```
> -rw-r----- 1 mysql adm      156038 Oct 30 20:10 error.log
> -rw-r----- 1 mysql adm           0 Oct 29 00:00 error.log.1
> ```

I did not need to change permissions on files.